# I want to auto increment a column and make it as a primary key in oracle10g. But on trigger creation I get an error

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle10g, sequence

I have created a Sequence for the table and on creation of a trigger I got the following error:

```
ORA-04089: cannot create triggers on objects owned by SYS.
```

Can someone explain me what is it and how can it be solved? Since I'm a beginner, is there a simple way to solve it?
MY TABLE NAME IS-testing.

```
create sequence example_seq 
start with 1
increment by 1
nomaxvalue;

create trigger example_trigger
before insert on testing
for each row
begin
select example_seq.nextval into :new.id from dual;
end;
```

Comment: Who is the owner of table `testing`? Do a `select * from user_tables` and what do you see there about this table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is quite clear:

```
ORA-04089: cannot create triggers on objects owned by SYS.
```

So obviously you are logged in as SYS, and creating objects in that user;s schemas.  You must not do this.  SYS is the user who owns the data dictionary and all the objects which manage the database.  Changing the SYS schema is, at best, bad practice and runs the risk of corrupting the database.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/dba.htm#ADMIN11040).

What you need to do is create a new user, for your application objects.  This is quite simple.  Connect as SYSTEM (avoid using SYS for menial tasks):

```
create user your_name_here identified by << password >>
/

grant create session, create table, create sequence, create trigger
     to your_name_here
/
```

Obviously you will need to grant more privileges.  The full list is [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9013.htm#SQLRF55037).

Once you've created your new user you can connect to it and create all the objects you desire.

Comment: I went to the administration option and created a new user giving a new password and a new user name. Then granted it all the privileges and also made the new user as a DBA. Then logged out from sys and logged in using the new user. I was successful in creating the trigger without any error. Is it OK if I continue using this new user for all my database activities?

Comment: Sure, why wouldn't it be?